# Output HTML and images from a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

There are many examples on the Net of outputting images from servlets by writing to request's output buffer.
Is it possible to create an entire HTML page with multiple images in a table from a servlet?
The images would be created on the fly by a bean.

Comment: How big are the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to do it that way.

I would create two servlets:

1. To serve an HTML page with `<img src="...">` elements for each image.
2. To serve the binary data of the image

Basically the first servlet would send the HTML to the client browser. The browser sends new HTTP requests for each `<img>` element it finds. The second servlet would handle those requests by writing the image's binary data directly to the response's `OutputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

For small images, you can embed the images using css or directly in html.
To embed using css take a look at [this](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/).

This is what I would suggest:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img alt="some title" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA.."/>
    <img alt="some title" src="data:image/png;base64<data2>"/>
    <img alt="some title" src="data:image/png;base64<data2>"/>
  </body>
</html
```

To get the exact value you should have after base64 in src attribute, you should take a look at [converting png images to base64](http://ben-bai.blogspot.com/2012/08/java-convert-image-to-base64-string-and.html).

This solution is somewhat non-ideal and might take the page to load forever if there are more than 10-15 images in the page.

If that is the case, then you should go with the other solution of linking to the url for servlets which serve image.